# How to reverse specific characters from a textbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, function, textbox, reverse

If I am using the StrReverse function to reverse text in a textbox when a button is pressed, how can I make it only reverse select letters?

For example:

**ABCDEFG**

becomes

**AFEDCBG**

(only reverses middle five characters)

Comment: Extract the middle part with SubString, reverse it, stitch things back together.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment you can use something like the following:

```
    Dim beforeReverse As String = "ABCDEFG"
    Dim afterReverse As String = beforeReverse.Substring(0, 1) &
        StrReverse(beforeReverse.Substring(1, Len(beforeReverse) - 2)) &
        beforeReverse.Substring(Len(beforeReverse) - 1, 1)
```